# Bridging a vlan and OpenVPN tap on Debian

Tags: networking, debian, openvpn, vlan

Under Debian I need to bridge a vlan `eth0.1` and tap `tap0`.  Usually, when bridging a normal ethernet adapter with a tap I would include something along the lines of this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
      pre-up /usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
      pre-up /usr/sbin/brctl addbr br0
      address 10.0.0.254
      network 10.0.0.0
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      post-up /sbin/ip link set tap0 up
      post-up /usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 tap0
      post-up /sbin/ip link set eth0 up
      post-up /usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 eth0
      post-down /sbin/ip link set br0 down
      post-down /usr/sbin/brctl delbr br0
      post-down /usr/sbin/openvpn --rmtun tap0
      post-down /sbin/ip link set eth0 down
```

Now, I will admit it is not pretty (we manually create the tun and the bridge using the raw commands) although it is the most Debian-like means I've found.  The problem comes when I want to replace `eth0` with a vlan, such as `eth0.1`.  The only way I can think of is manually adding `pre-up` and `post-down` commands to manually create the `eth0.1` vlan (with all others being configured the Debian way).

However, I am not totally sure then as the `post-down /sbin/ip link set eth0 down` may break other `eth0.x` vlans.  Can someone suggest a cleaner means of accomplishing my goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"the most Debian-like means I've found" -- you need to look harder, possibly in the `bridge-utils-interfaces`(5) man page.

Bridging VLAN interfaces is trivial; you just put the VLAN interface in as a manual one (ie `iface eth0.1 inet manual`) and then add `eth0.1` into the `bridge_ports` list.

A quick note on OpenVPN and it's Ethernet mode -- don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring up your tuntap device together with the vlan interface and bridge afterwards:

```
  # The physical network port
  allow-hotplug eth0
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet manual

  # The interface used for the bridge
  auto vlan1
  iface vlan1 inet manual
        vlan_raw_device eth0
        pre-up ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user openvpn-system-user
        pre-up ip link set tap0 up
        post-down ip link set tap0 down
        post-down ip tuntap del dev tap0 mode tap

  # The bridge interface
  auto br0
  iface br0 inet static
        pre-up ip link set vlan1 up
        pre-up ip link set tap0 up
        bridge_ports vlan1 tap0
        bridge_waitport 5
        bridge_waitmax 10
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_stp off
        address 10.0.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        boradcast 10.0.0.255
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1
        dns-search-domain openvpn.example.net
        post-down ip link set tap0 down
        post-down ip link set vlan1 down
```

You need to adjust the user you want the tap interface to be owned and of course all ip settings and timings.

You need to have the vlan and bridge-utils package installed for your setup to work.

This setup up is even possible on a bonded ethernet interface: I described it in the [Debian network configuration for a briged tap on a bonded interface with VLAN Pseudo-HOW-TO](http://ente.limmat.ch/kb/linux/networking/bonding_vlan_bridge_tap_config.html).